# How to select next row automatically in Qt tableView whenever a pushbutton is pressed?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt5, qtableview

I have a **Qt tableView** that loads the data from the **SQLite database** and I have configured it in such a way that in the default view, the *first row is automatically selected* and I can *execute a query on that row* by pressing a **button-'Present'**. Now, I want my program to *automatically select the next row* after I pressed the 'button' for the **first time** so that the when I press 'Present' for the **second time**, the query is executed on the second row. So, basically, I want to **change the selection of row** whenever a button is pressed until the end of row numbers is reached.

I have searched quite a few sites for the solution, but I could not get the one for my problem.

Code for viewing table **s_info** and selecting the first row as default.

```
void table::on_view_clicked() 
{
MainWindow conn;
QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();

conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery* qry= new QSqlQuery(conn.info);

qry->prepare("Select Name,Roll_No from s_info order by Roll_no");
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);
ui-> tableView ->setModel(modal);
ui->tableView-> setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tableView->selectRow(0);
ui->tableView->setFocus();

conn.connClose();
qDebug()<< (modal->rowCount());
}
```

Code for the execution of a query when a button name 'Present' is clicked.
**Note** that I have performed query execution based on Column **Roll_No** in my **s_info** table and *index of Roll No for the 1st row is(0,1)*

```
void table::on_present_clicked()

{
QAbstractItemModel *model = ui->tableView->model();
QModelIndex index = model->index(0,1);
QString roll= (index.data().toString());
MainWindow conn;
conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery qry;
QSqlTableModel modal;
qry.prepare("Update s_info set Present_Days=Present_Days + 1 where 
Roll_No='"+roll+"'");
qry.exec();

conn.connClose();
}
```

I expect that when I click a **Present** for the second time, the row selection is shifted to the second row and the query is executed on that row. I want this to occur until I reached the end of the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example illustrates what you are going to achieve. The key-point is that you are going to need an `QItemSelectionModel`, which manages you selection. Very often one forgets to explicitly set the model of the `QItemSelectionModel` being the model of the view.

Now, if you will select one row in an table view the next button will select the next row. Selecting the next row basically means to select all columns in the next row.

It shouldn't matter if you are using something like an `QSqlTableModel` the usage should be simply the same.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    auto tableView = new QTableView;
    tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::SingleSelection);
    tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior::SelectRows);
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    tableView->setModel(model);
    auto selectionModel = new QItemSelectionModel;
    selectionModel->setModel(model);
    tableView->setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(tableView);
    auto button = new QPushButton("Next");
    frame->layout()->addWidget(button);
    model->setRowCount(10);
    model->setColumnCount(10);
    frame->show();
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]()
    {
        auto indices = selectionModel->selectedIndexes();
        if (indices.isEmpty()) return;
        QModelIndexList empty;
        selectionModel->select(QModelIndex(), QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag::Clear);
        for (auto index : indices)
        {
            auto newIndex=index.sibling(index.row() + 1, index.column());
            selectionModel->select(newIndex,QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag::Select);
        }
    });
    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new selection model? Isn't it enough to get the one the view automatically creates after `setModel()`?