# selecting next/previowus record in Qt TableView

Tags: qt, plugins, pyqt, tableview, qtableview

I have the same problem as was presented here:
[How to select next row automatically in Qt tableView whenever a pushbutton is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016509/how-to-select-next-row-automatically-in-qt-tableview-whenever-a-pushbutton-is-pr/73061847?noredirect=1#comment129111418_73061847)

but I use Qt platform with python (qgis.PyQt), so I can't translate one-to-one as in presented above (where is c++).
Can you see what in code from attached below is wrong?

```
def NextOne(self):
    #ind = self.dlg.tableView_3.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
    self.dlg.tableView_3.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.SingleSelection)
    self.dlg.tableView_3.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectionBehavior.SelectRows)
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    self.dlg.tableView_3.setModel(model)
    selModel = QItemSelectionModel()
    selModel.setModel(model)
    self.dlg.tableView_3.setSelectionModel(selModel)
    ind=selModel.selectedIndexes()
    print (ind)
    if (ind.isEmpty()):
        return
    else:
        selModel.select(QModelIndex(), model.SelectionFlag.clear)
        row = selectionModel.selection().indexes().row()
        print (row)
        for i in ind:
            nast = i.sibling(i.row()+1,i.colmun())
            selModel.select(nast,model.SelectionFlag.Select)
    return
```

The code for first and last looks that:

```
 def first(self):
    self.dlg.tableView_3.selectRow(0)
    self.SelekcjaRzedu()

def last(self):
    num = self.model4.rowCount()
    self.dlg.tableView_3.selectRow(num-1)
    self.SelekcjaRzedu()
```

Comment: Is your code not working? What does the python interpreter say? It helps us to help you if you post your error message, etc.

Comment: Does model.SelectionFlag.Select work? I typically saw `QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag.Select` instead.

Comment: it says: if (ind.isEmpty()):  'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'

Answer (score 0):

It says that the error you are getting is: `if (ind.isEmpty()): 'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'`.

[QModelIndexList QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes) const returns a [QList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndexList-typedef).

Since the `QList` gets bound to the native python list, this is what you should write in python to have idiomatic python:

```
if not ind:
    return
```

Comment: OK it doesn't take an error, but in else printed row is empty - [] and all records disappear

Comment: dissappear in TableView

Comment: @KarolŚpila: `selectionModel` is incorrect since you use `selModel` at other places. I feel like you are going beyond a single Q/A here though towards a complete project for you.

Comment: I put a current in answer above